# "Site Missing" error when invoking Direct Line API to generate a token

Tags: botframework

When I invoke the Direct Line API(using Postman) to generate a token based on a secret, I am getting an error that says "code": "BadArgument", "message": "Site Missing".
I am sending a POST request with the Authorization set to "Bearer Token".

Comment: I have the same issue. has it fixed ?

Comment: If you are still experiencing the issue, can you please post the how you are constructing your request (i.e. the endpoint called, headers, etc.)? I tested just now without any issue.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem - make sure you're not using the App Service Extension Keys that show up front and center when you open the DirectLine configuration.
You have to click on the site (either Default Site or whatever site you've made) and then use one of the secret keys from there.
They switched the positioning of these around from the previous UI, so these can be easily confused.